# Sort multiple DataGridView columns in one and export to CSV

Tags: c#, csv, sorting, datagridview, multiple-columns

I am coding an SQL-Client where u can export the DataGridView to CSV (Excel).
The problem is that I have multiple entries in the cell named "ID" like there is 4 times ID 21 but with different phone numbers. Is it possible to sort them before export to CSV that there is only on row with ID 21 and the phone numbers are separated with a "," ?

This is my code at the moment:

```
private void ButtonDataGridInCSVExport(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridViewResult.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    string csvheader = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewResult.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        csvheader += dataGridViewResult.Columns[i].Name + ";";
    }

    stringBuilder.Append(csvheader + Environment.NewLine);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in dataGridViewResult.Rows)
    {
        if (!dataGridViewRow.IsNewRow)
        {

            for (int c = 0; c < dataGridViewRow.Cells.Count; c++)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(dataGridViewRow.Cells[c].FormattedValue + ";");
            }
            stringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv";
    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName, false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("CSV file saved.");
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to make this possible?

This is how it looks like now:
[How it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCrme.png)

This is how it should look like:
[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqme5.png)

Comment: A kind of strange datastructure, why is there even a type column to begin with when you have seperate columns for each type? Why are there multiple rows with only 1-2 columns filled instead of 1 row where all columns are filled? But, that wasn't your question - to solve your problem I would recommend using `GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Type })` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby - additionally, you should consider instead of reading the UI (DataGrid, Cells) to read the ItemsSource and the object behind it

Comment: To be honest.. I dont even know why the datastructure is this kind of strange..
The field that are empty.. I dont know it is already in the database I guess..